# I am using a limited keyboard and would like to change my Windows 10 system shortcut keys?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-customization

I am looking for ways of customizing Windows 10 system in order to adjust it to my habits. I am especially used to editable shortcuts for the window manager actions (minimize, maximize, tile/arrange left/right) the way I have them in Linux.

[By default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) these are triggered in Windows 10 with <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Arrow_keys</kbd>. But on my laptop I have just one Windows (<kbd>Win</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd>) key on the left side of the keyboard, while the arrows are on the right, so that each such key-shortcut action can hardly be made with one hand. (It seems to me that using both hands for a shortcut falls short of a short-key's basic purpose – of avoiding such extravagant bodily movements!)

...And in case shortcuts can be edited I would like to be able to remove/replace those that are totally useless to me, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> which does the same as <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, when I never lock the desktop in this way, <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, which launches something called feedback hub which I don't know what it is, and that I'll probably never use...

*Is there a way to edit the default Windows 10 shortcuts (for window manager and other actions) or of adding new ones, so that each such shortcut could be used easily with just one hand?*

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to change the behavior of the maximize button etc, or alter keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @LPChip - My main goal is having shortcuts for window actions, like minimize, maximize, snap/tile to left-right that would not involve two hands: preferably Super+left_side_letter. (e.g. in Linux I prefer Super+X to minimize). After that I would like to be able to change other shortcuts too, like launching some programs maybe (e.g. Super+F to launch Firefox not the feedback hub etc), that's why I'm posing the question as one of principle. Maybe there are third-party apps that can add this flexibility.  - By the way: what do you mean by `the maximize button`? Shortcuts is the only topic here.

Comment: Winkey + arrows to move the window. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/default-keyboard-shortcuts/?ID=511174db-ec91-498c-9801-3fc14559d0f1 for more advanced stuff if you install DisplayFusion

Comment: @cipricus Did you not notice the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager link?

Comment: @Gantendo - indeed I didn't. It seems as the answer.

Comment: @Gantendo - I've tested it. Have you? It doesn't work for the short-keys I'm interested in (Win-Arrows) even after reboot and/or running it as administrator. I'll keep looking and give feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @cipricus I have, but it was a long long time ago.

Comment: @Gantendo - I'll remove it, it succeeds in disabling the default shortcuts without replacing them...

Comment: FWIW, I edited your question to get to the core of it right away. As originally stated, the question never clearly states what the issue is. Also, please do not beg for people not to downvote in the body of a question. It’s not a good idea and it comes off as desperate. In general, don’t worry about downvotes. Just post your question as clearly as possible.

Comment: Which key would you like to sacrifice to get a right win key or to swap with left win key. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/second-tab-key/dfebbc4b-00fa-4167-be3f-fc65cd0c56e9

Comment: @user1292580 - *I want the left_Winkey to stay as it is*, but  if a *second* one could be added I would prefer that to be the right_Control, the right_AltGr or the Alt_Shift (and thus use it in combination with the arrows).

Comment: @user1292580 - I think I'll try this myself: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/remap-your-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by @user1292580 I have guessed that a single key could be remapped to be a right Win key. And that is the case. I have found an article on AutoHotkey [here](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/remap-your-keyboard), linking also [to the precise instructions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#other-useful-remappings) on how to **remap the Right_Ctrl as a Right_Win**

- install AutoHotkey
- right-click in Explorer: New > AutoHotkey script
- open that in Notepad or right-click on it and "Edit script"
- add the line `RCtrl::RWin`, save and close, double-click to execute the script; it should already work.
- copy the script to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, so it will automatically run every time you turn on your computer

Maybe completely remapping the <kbd>Right_Ctrl</kbd> key is not the best idea, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>key is useful on the right for other purposes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to set "italics" in Office for example).

Changing the approach: whole combinations of keys can be remapped instead of one. In this way, for example, **<kbd>Left_Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down_Arrow</kbd> can be remapped to do the same as <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Down_Arrow</kbd> and so forth** (thus without changing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> itself).

Thus:

```
>^Up::Sendinput #{Up}
>^Down::SendInput #{Down}
>^Left::SendInput #{Left}
>^Right::SendInput #{Right}
```

(`^` stands for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `>^` for <kbd>Right_Ctrl</kbd>, `Up` etc for the respective arrow-keys, `!` for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, `#` for <kbd>Win</kbd>. Something like `>^Up::#Up` should work too, and it does to minimize and maximize but oddly not for arranging to left and right.)

or, with other keys:

```
^!x::WinMinimize A
^!e::WinMaximize A
!e::Sendinput #{Up}
!x::Sendinput #{Down}
!s::SendInput #{Left}
!d::SendInput #{Right}
```

(`WinMinimize A` is different from `#Down` in that the former triggers direct minimization and the latter unmaximizes first.)

Other shortcuts:

- Start Firefox with <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>: `#f::Run Firefox`

(Setting a default shortcut to trigger a different action remaps that shortcut.)

- Run a desktop shortcut for executing `%windir%\explorer.exe ms-settings-connectabledevices:devicediscovery`, the interface to connect devices, with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>: `!b::Run "C:\Users\cip\Desktop\Connect Wireless Display and Audio Devices.lnk"`
- Start Task manager with <kbd>Left_Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>: `<^Esc::Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Task Manager.lnk"`
- Remap some <kbd>F</kbd>-keys to adjust volume without pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>:

`F7::SendInput {Volume_Mute}`

`F8::SendInput {Volume_Down}`

`F9::SendInput {Volume_Up}`